# How to use Facebook SDK in Dart?

Tags: javascript, facebook, dart

I'm using this code for Facebook SDK initialization

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId  : '{app id}',
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        xfbml  : true
    });
};

(function(d){
    var js, 
        id = 'facebook-jssdk', 
        ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement('script'); 
    js.id = id; 
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

In order to use personal data from Facebook, I use these methods in Dart code

```dart
void showFacebook(Event e, var detail, Node target) {
  JsObject fb = context["FB"];
  fb.callMethod("getLoginStatus", [checkLoginStatusCallback]);
}

void checkLoginStatusCallback(response) {
  print("checkLoginStatusCallback");
  if(response["status"] == "connected") {
    showPhoto(response["authResponse"]["userID"]);
  } 
  else {
    authUser();
  }
}

void authUser() {
  print("authUser");
  JsObject fb = context["FB"];
  fb.callMethod("login", [loginCallback]);
}

void loginCallback (response) {
  print("loginCallback");
  if(response["authResponse"]) {
    showPhoto(response["authResponse"]["userID"]);
  } 
}
```

But initialization fails with error `Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: The string contains invalid characters.`

Diving deeper into Facebook SDK I've found the reason of that error. Init function trying to create an iframe for sending http requests

```js
httpProxyFrame = createIframe({
    url: httpDomain + proxyUrl,
    name: 'fb_xdm_frame_http',
    id: 'fb_xdm_frame_http',
    root: container,
    'aria-hidden':true,
    title: IFRAME_TITLE,
    'tab-index': -1
});
```

Function `createIframe` does this check

```js
if (hasNamePropertyBug()) {
    frame = document.createElement('<iframe name="' + name + '"/>');
} else {
    frame = document.createElement("iframe");
    frame.name = name;
}
```

Function `hasNamePropertyBug` does this

```js
function hasNamePropertyBug() {
    return typeof hasBug === 'undefined'
        ? test()
        : hasBug;
}; 

function test() {
    var form = document.createElement("form"),
               input = form.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
    input.name = guid();
    hasBug = input !== form.elements[input.name];
    form = input = null;
    return hasBug;
};
```

As far as `document.createElement` uses Dart's `domCreateElement` function, which wraps an element, the `hasBug` variable becomes equal `true` because it compares `GeneratedWrapper` wrapper with an element.

So, `hasNamePropertyBug` returns `true` and this code throws an error

```js
document.createElement('<iframe name="' + name + '"/>');
```

So, my question is how to use the Facebook SDK within the Dart environment?

Comment: Not the most elegant solution, but `hasBug` seems to global - how about just setting it to `true` before doing any FB stuff? The name property bug should only apply to IE7 and below, which isn't supported by Dart anyway. If you don't have to cater to legacy browsers, this might be viable.

Comment: @MarioP take a look at http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js `hasBug` is a local variable of `hasNamePropertyBug` function which is created dynamically. Seems like it easier to override entire `hasNamePropertyBug` function, but I'm not sure it's possible

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it still looks like it's defined on the global object. `var hasBug;`, right above some empty lines and the definition of function `test()`.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I relied on source intendation too much. Then I'm out of ideas, sorry :-/

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem ? Just got the same issue !

Comment: Nope. Started using Angular instead of Dart.

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippets, the SDK isn't being initialized. You assign `window.fbAsyncInit` to a function that initializes the SDK, but that function is never called.

Comment: `window.fbAsyncInit` called dynamically after SDK script has been loaded. Take a look at http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js search `fbAsyncInit` keyword and you'll get it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

After inspection of this bug, I found the problem was inside the shadown_dom package, not dart itself.

Since for now I am targeting browsers with native shadown dom support anyway, removing `<script src="packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.min.js"></script>` solved this problem for me (but breaks backward compatibility).